# Joomla 2.5.x: Multiple instances of a module not working in the same page?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I am testing my module in Joomla 2.5.x and I've noticed that duplicating the module in the same page does not seem to work. I've noticed that it's because my module has a common `addScript()` and `addStyleSheet()` functions. For example, I have the following code in my module:

```
$document->addScript(JURI::base() . 'modules/mod_mymodule/js/abc.js');
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base() . 'modules/mod_mymodule/css/xyz.css');
```

It looks like every time I duplicate a module, Joomla 2.5.x tries to **re-include** these and since they are already included by the first module, it fails and the multiple modules don't render properly in the page.

Joomla 3.x however seems smart enough to detect and include these scripts only once in the header. Is there a way to resolve this issue in 2.5.x?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
JURI::base(true)
```

instead of

```
JURI::base()
```

so the scheme, host and port won't be included, this should be enough for J 2.5 to see that the scripts are one and the same.

It is bad practice to include the host in the scripts unless they're on another host.  Besides issues with caching on multi-subdomain sites you're just making your page bigger for no reason.

Comment: I guess so. But I checked the implementation of both addScript() and head.php:render(), it should work also with full urls, it's puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid adding those twice you need to keep track of the fact that you've already added that.

You could use a Singleton pattern to do that and have class with an `initialize()` method that will add the required data into the `JDocument` only once.

Or, you could add a property in the `JDocument` object itself that you can then test for later on. (Not ideal, since with this practice you risk a property name clash).

Finally, you could try to inspect the `JDocument`'s list of styles and scripts (if it's publicly visible) to see if you already added them. This I think is not very efficient.

So I'd go with the Singleton approach, where the module code calls a `initialize()` method that will add your styles and scripts only once.

Another possible problem is to check if the module template uses element IDs instead of classes. Then you will likely have ID clashes as well.